# .NET Timers, do they fire at the exact interval or after processing + interval

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, thread-sleep

So a simple enough question really.

How exactly does the interval for System.Timers work?

Does it fire 1 second, each second, regardless of how long the timeout event takes or does it require the routine to finish first and then restarts the interval?

So either:

1. 1 sec....1 sec....1 sec and so on
2. 1 sec + process time....1 sec + process time....1 sec + process time and so on

The reason I ask this is I know my "processing" takes much less than 1 second but I would like to fire it every one second on the dot (or as close as).

I had been using a Thread.Sleep method like so:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000 - ((int)(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds) >= 1000 ? 0 : (int)(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds)));
```

Where start time is registered at start of the routine. <strike>The problem here is that Thread.Sleep only works in milliseconds</strike>. So my routine could restart at 1000ms or a fraction over like 1000.0234ms, which can happen as one of my routines takes 0ms according to "TimeSpan" but obviously it has used ticks/nanoseconds - which would then mean the timing is off and is no longer every second. <strike>If I could sleep by ticks or nanoseconds it would be bang on.</strike>

If number 1 applies to System.Timers then I guess I'm sorted. <strike>If not I need some way to "sleep" the thread to a higher resolution of time i.e ticks/nanoseconds.</strike>

You might ask why I do an inline IF statement, well sometimes the processing can go above 1000ms so we need to make sure we don't create a minus figure. Also, by the time we determine this, the ending time has changed slightly - not by much, but, it could make the thread delay slightly longer causing the entire subsequent sleeping off.

**I know, I know, the time would be negligible... but what happens if the system suddenly stalled for a few ms... it would protect against that in this case.**

**Update 1**

Ok. So I didn't realise you can put a TimeSpan in as the timing value. So I used the below code:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) - ((DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds >= 1000) ? TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0) : DateTime.Now.Subtract(start)));
```

If I am right, this should then allow me to repeat the thread at exactly 1 second - or as close as the system will allow.

Comment: Windows is not a realtime operating system. Your question implies that you would like it to be. If that's the case then you're going to have to learn to live with disappointment. Timers are by their nature inexact in a multithreaded operating system like Windows. What are you doing that such small differences are relevant?

Comment: It's not that it needs to be real-time. I just would like it to fire as close to one second as possible each iteration which is why the timer method is more suited.

Comment: You need to state the tolerances you are willing to accept, in particular the maximum theoretical difference you might experience and the consequences of it not responding in time. If you're writing rocket control and the like you need hard real time. Most people don't but we can't know without context.

Comment: @Eric: Out of curiosity, since you said "Timers are by their nature inexact in a multithreaded operating system", is there no way to have exact timers in a multi-threaded application? Or do they have to limited to single threaded applications for this kind of thing to be designed?

Comment: @Joan: It's not that the *application* is multithreaded, it's that the *entire operating system* is multithreaded.  Think about it this way: suppose somehow the timer does fire exactly every second on the second, guaranteed. What mysterious force causes the operating system to *not switch to a different process* one nanosecond after the event handler starts running? By the time it switches back, a sixteenth of a second might have gone by!

Comment: Thanks Eric, so are you saying when the OS switches to a different process, the timer in the other process stops, or does not account the time passed? Sorry I am not very familiar with these things, was just wondering (:

Comment: @Joan when you sleep a thread you are saying to the OS "I'm okay to sleep for a while". You can specify any precision you like but you be limited by the thread scheduler's algorithms. On most modern windows machines the thread quantum (smallest unit of time a thread gets to do work before being rescheduled for something of the same priority that is waiting" is 15 milliseconds. thus asking for less than this is largely pointless. There are *vast depths* of complexity to this, and if you want to know the Windows Internals book (get the latest) by Marc Russinovich is the one to read

Comment: @Joan like I said *state your requirements* and we can tell you how you can achieve them (note that some requirements will entail not using windows, some will entail using specific hardware, some will entail running on a hard realtime OS)

Comment: Thanks ShuggyCoUk, I like knowing about stuff like that even though it's over my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you have set `AutoReset = true;` then your theory 1 is true, otherwise you would have to deal with it in code – see [the docuementation for `Timer` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).